# How can a Mac or Unix owner fix/develop webpages for IE6/IE7?

Tags: web-development, windows, internet-explorer

I work on Debian and before Debian I was on Ubuntu. In my previous job, we simply ignored IE6, but at my present job a page must work flawlessly for IE6 onwards. The one wayout for me is to set up a Windows VM but that doesn't help every time. Consider this, if I was a freelance consultant and didn't want to or have enough money to buy licenses for every possible Windows version how could I deliver a web page that worked for IE6/IE7?

Comment: Why must it work in IE6? I mean, MS, google, facebook, everyone doesn't support IE6...

Comment: according to http://www.theie6countdown.com/default.aspx 11%users are still hooked to IE6, not sure about IE7 but I think the number is higher than 11%, so at least 22% of users are using IE6/7, my organisation does not want to miss this share and hence things **must** work in IE6/7

Comment: 70% of that is in Korea, China and India. Regardless of what your company is making, it's not really a market that will bite, even if it does work in IE6...(note that I'm talking specifically about 6 here)

Comment: ah well, only if I could ignore them, am being paid to get PITA for IE6/7 bugs :P

Comment: Ok, a second question: Why do you keep mentioning 7? it's a very much improved version of IE that everyone still supports(bit out of date now, but not as broken as 6)

Comment: well, I am stuck at z-index stacking issue in IE6 and IE7, only 2 browsers, PITA/PITB/PITN, B = back, N = Neck

Comment: @Trezoid, i had div layout bug, i was testing under IE6 and bug appeared under IE7 _only_. So please don't talk about IE7 being so much better. I have to do a lot of work regarding IE and believe me - IE7 just as bad as IE6. Well ok i'm being harsh, its not AS bad as IE6, but the point i want to tell is that IE7 is still a pain in the ass to work with...

Comment: @Trezoid, what browsers someone should be supporting should be based on who *their* visitors are not on what *other* businesses choose to support or not. Where I work (sadly) more than 15% of our customers are still on IE6...

Comment: exactly the same issue with me, not sure about the exact % but significant number of users are on IE6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet would be to setup a windows VM, (Or several) or find an older computer which already has windows on it.

Not sure what else you can do.

Comment: Well, it turns out that most of the suggestions are pointing to VM.

Comment: I'm developing under Linux. Solution is yet the same... Probably the best one too, since you get all the tools you like for developing and only do the testing in environment you don't really want to be in.

Comment: vmware player works really nicely under e.g. Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess this is the best solution, I also found this http://internet-explorer-collection.en.softonic.com/, I can get a copy of WinXP and install this to have all the possible IEs I need :-) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

Set up a separate machine (not a vm) with Windows - if you use a suitable version you can remote desktop to it.  On said machine, install one or more of the images found on http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef - there is an XP with IE6.

This will hopefully allow you to test all you need with a minimal investment.

Comment: +1: Windows PC with IE is cheap.  Don't mess with anything too complex.  Buy  a used machine on eBay.

Comment: @S.Lott:  Can you get a new PC with XP on it any more?  You may have to hit eBay or Craigslist to get one.

Comment: This is the most reliable way, VM's will not always behave exactly the same. And @DavidThornley, yes you can get new machines with XP, that's all my company gets. :(

Comment: Also the VPC's are a really nice way to get it all running on a single box.  You cannot do that if you are already inside a virtual machine.

Answer (score 4):

[**IEs 4 Linux**](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page) (don't mind the name, works on OSX and BSD too).

It's basically collection of various versions of IE pre-packaged to use [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/). 
Good enough for quick checks. If you want to do in depth check, like for example how will that behave on IE7 on WinXP, then you do need to set up VM.

BTW. Microsoft has officially [killed IE6 and promotes migration to IE8](http://www.theie6countdown.com/).

Comment: you will be surprised to note that IE6 is an "A grade browser" according to Yahoo!, I used IEs 4 Linux, it wasn't stable :(

Comment: @Kumar: for IE6 worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I develop a web site on my Mac. When testing IE, I use a virtual machine running Parallels. The only variations I currently test are: IE6, IE7 and IE8 all running under XP. Based upon this, I have not had any real problems slip past. That being said, I use ExtJs which handles *most* of the browser specific stuff.

I have XP installed on one VM which I then cloned forwards. The XP is legit, but I doubt the clones are. My work has just got a MDSN subscription, so I'm covered now.

If you absolutely must test under multiple O/S versions then I'd suggest a MSDN subscription - they are not that expensive anymore. This includes all O/S installs. If your employer or client (as a freelancer) is demanding this level of testing, then I'd pass the cost on to them.

BTW: Half of our client base still run IE6. I wish we could ignore it, but that's just not feasible.